# Bootcamp windows10: how to connect two dualshock 4 using bluetooth?

Tags: windows, macos, bluetooth, boot-camp, game-controller

I'm not sure what is the best place to ask this question, so I decided to ask Microsoft, Apple and superuser communities.

I spend whole day fighting with it and still no luck so I hope that anyone can help me.

The problem: I have MacBook Pro 2019 with latest Catalina and latest windows 10 installed from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 using bootcamp. Windows and bootcamp drivers were installed succesfully. Now I want to play something (why else you need windows on mac right :)) and I have TWO original PS dualshock 4 controllers and I want to pair both of them with windows. But I'm able to connect only one controller.

Step by step reproduction of the problem:

1) Turn on windows bluetooth
2) Press PS + Share buttons on both controllers
3) Controllers start to flash lights - that means they are ready to connect
4) See two "Wireless Controller" options in the bluetooth list
5) Pick the first one and it connects succesfully within a few seconds (1-3s, very fast)
6) Go back to the bluetooth devices list and pick the second controller and it fails to connect

Pre-conditions:

1) Both controllers connect and work perfect separately and work great in pair on "native" windows pc.
2) Both controllers work great in pair and separately in osx
3) I want it to be wireless so I didn't tried it using cable but I think it will work
4) I didn't tried to reset controllers because both of them work great separately in the same system (windows)

What I tried already:

1)I installed latest updates for osx and windows
2)I downloaded and installed latest bootcamp drivers
3)I removed and installed again all windows bluetooth devices and drivers
4)I tried many hacks and tricks from answers.microsoft forum but it didn't help
5)I tried to rename controllers

I will be very appreciate for any help.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Older bluetooth modules can only do one connection at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootcamp drivers for Bluetooth are notoriously troublesome.

I am answering this from a Mac Book Pro 14,1 2017 model running Bootcamp and Windows 10.
Although I do use Bluetooth for some devices, I do get problems...

The Bluetooth mouse I use most of the time frequently suffers from lag, especially it seems when downloading large files over the WiFi network. Also using a Bluetooth Speaker is not really an option because of frequent gaps in the playback. Also I can say these are not issues when running Mac OS on the computer.

When investigating the drivers further I find that even though Bootcamp has all of its updates, the driver for the Bluetooth is dated 2006. With a driver that old it is no wonder it has limitations. If you search the internet for problems related to Bluetooth and specifically the Bootcamp drivers you will find many people with issues, but finding a working solution is something that has so far eluded me. It is possible to reset the Bluetooth stack when using Mac OS, but I cannot say if it will solve your problem.

My answer to your question is that the driver offered by the manufacturer for Bootcamp and thus Windows 10 is old, very old and therefore limited.